# Overlapping inline elements that span container width

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I am trying to create a "bookshelf" style navigation with overlapping elements in a container that is responsive. The number of books needs to be dynamic, I need their spacing to be based on container width, and number of books to create and offset for each book till it fills the container.

I have set up a little codepen test and I am very close, however it isn't dynamic and I am not quite reaching the farthest edge of the container with my last element.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/DurbanVisuals/pen/bNjgvL)

```
book.each(function (i) {
  var num = i;
  $(this).css({
      marginLeft: (num * (margin - 10)),
      zIndex: (book.length) - num
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi not sure but I hope this was what you meant

```
book.each(function (i) {
  var v = container.width();
  var w = book.width();
  var x = (book.length - 1);
  var vw = ((v - w)/x);
  var num = i;
  $(this).css({
   left: (num * vw) + 'px',
   zIndex: (x) - num
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbjRoW

Comment: Thank you, I just found out about the vw, vh units last week. In my research they are well supported across browsers. Is this the same for you? Thanks this works exactly like I needed.